# Can a Client Link to My JavaScript, Hosted on a Different Domain?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cross-domain

Is it possible for me to supply a client with a snippet of HTML which contains a reference to a javascript file that I host? They want to paste this HTML into their CMS, so that when their page loads, it'll load our content.

I was under the impression that there was cross domain security preventing this from being possible.

What if, instead of linking to the JavaScript, I gave them the snippet of HTML with the JavaScript already included

so instead of

```
<div>
    <!-- link to js -->
</div>
```

I gave them

```
<div>
    $.get(/*url to my content*/);
</div>
```

Would that work?

Comment: When you say "load our content", is this content javascript, or is there more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [JSONP](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) to simulate cross domain AJAX calls (works only with GET requests as internally it uses a `script` tag):

```
$.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=cat&tagmode=any&format=json&jsoncallback=?",
    function(data) {
        $.each(data.items, function(i,item) {
            $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo("#images");
            if ( i == 3 ) return false;
        });
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible for me to supply a client with a snippet of HTML which contains a reference to a javascript file that I host?

Yes. The src of script elements has no same origin limits.

> `$.get(/*url to my content*/);`

XMLHttpRequests still do have same origin limits. XHR can only fetch from the domain of the **page**, not the script.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML `<script>` tags are exempt from the same origin policy, so if your client links to your JavaScript file with `<script>` tags, you will not have any problems. ([Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP))

Comment: @Daniel, thanks but I'm not sure what you mean here - what do you mean by the client linking to my js file with <script> tags?

Answer (score 0):

Referencing a javascript file from a different domain is no problem. This is not cross site scripting, it's simply a cross site HTTP request. This is used a lot, e.g. by Google's JavaScript API Loader.